# Swift 3 Multipart form/data Upload- URLSession gets 206 response code/Alamofire receives 406

Tags: swift, multipartform-data, urlsession

I am trying to upload data to our server. The data is a zip file converted in to `Data`.

```
SSZipArchive.createZipFile(atPath: "\(self.currentWPDirectory!)/\(self.documentId!).zip", withFilesAtPaths: checkInFileList)

let zipData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "file:///\(self.currentWPDirectory!)/\(self.documentId!).zip")!)
```

**URLSession**

```
let parameters = "?documentId=\(self.documentId!)&documentAction=CHECKIN&doc_action_comment=some comment&device_name=\(UIDevice.current.name)"
let urlString = "\(Constants.WebService.checkIn)\(parameters)"
let url = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

let data = zipData

request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue

let boundary = "----------SwIfTeRhTtPrEqUeStBoUnDaRy"
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
let body = NSMutableData();

let tempData = NSMutableData()
let fileName = "FILE_NAME" + ".zip"
let parameterName = "userfile"

let mimeType = "application/octet-stream"

tempData.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
let fileNameContentDisposition = fileName != "" ? "filename=\"\(fileName)\"" : ""
let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; \(fileNameContentDisposition)\r\n"
tempData.append(contentDisposition.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
tempData.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
tempData.append(zipData)
tempData.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

body.append(tempData as Data)

body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.httpBody = body as Data

let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let task = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: data) { (data, response, err) in

    // Gets 206 in response
}
task.resume()
```

**Alamofire**

```
let params = [
    "documentId": self.documentId!,
    "documentAction": (self.isSync) ? "SYNC" : "CHECKIN",
    "doc_action_comment": "Some Comment",
    "device_name": UIDevice.current.name
]

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        multipartFormData.append(zipData, withName: "FILE_DATA", fileName: "\(self.documentId!).zip", mimeType: "application/zip")
        for (key, value) in params {
            multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
    to: "\(Constants.WebService.checkIn)?documentId=\(self.documentId!)&documentAction=\((self.isSync) ? "SYNC" : "CHECKIN")&doc_action_comment=comment&device_name=\(UIDevice.current.name)",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                        // Get 406 Response code
                        // Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."
                    }
                    self.completionCallback!(true)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                self.completionCallback!(false)
            }
        }
    )
```

I have tried many ways to get multipart form/data uploads to send my data, with no success. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you solved this?